# Android 6.0 device not recognized by adb on Linux after reboot

Tags: linux, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

In Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with Android 6.0, when the device is rebooted, phone complains that the connected computer doesn't recognize the phone and the device is not any more reachable over ADB from the connected Linux PC. The phone in fact instructs user to install proper drivers for Windows or Mac OS, but as the phone is connected to Linux host, there is no help here.

This means, that in order to continue debugging over ADB, one must manually toggle the USB mode from phone from MTP to PTP, after which phone is connected through ADB again. This makes test automation impossible, as the test scheduler needs to reboot the target device between test rounds.

With previous Android versions, rebooting the device remotely and getting ADB connection back was possible, but with Android 6.0, this became a problem. This particular device had earlier Android 5.1 and there were no problems with remote reboots.

As manually toggling of USB mode solves the problem, it might help, if this mode could be automatically toggled after reboot. So far, only solutions I have seen require device rooting and that is out of question.

Does someone have any idea, how Android 6.0 device could be automatically recognized by ADB after reboot?

Comment: I asked this question from Samsung and their answer was, that they can't help as the problem is on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was after all simple: the Linux user, who starts up the adb server, needed to be added to the "plugdev" group. This group was defined in file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules with line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

With previous Android versions, this didn't seem to be important as we didn't have any users in that group and everything worked fine.